# Sharepoint 2013 Javascript object model IE compatibility

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I am trying to inject some JS code into a wiki page to allow LaTex markup to be rendered using the MathJax library. After a bit of playing around I realised that I needed to run the MathJax script when the page was NOT in edit mode. It would appear that the MS JS client library for SP2013 has a neat way of checking

```
var InEditMode = SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.isInEditMode();

if(!InEditMode){

 // load MathJax library from CDN
}
```

This works great for recent versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE10+, but fails on IE9 and below. The reported JS error is that *SP.Ribbon. is null or undefined*

Although I cannot be sure, it would appear that SP2013 supports IE9, but looking at the header of the SP wiki page source I see

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

**Question**: Does SP2013 support IE9? If not, is there an alternative way to check whether the page state is in Edit mode?

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work? I'm trying to do the same and can't find any solution that works properly. I've created a question on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865427/add-mathjax-script-to-pages-in-office-365-sharepoint
It would be great if you could give your solution there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Plan browser support in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526%28v=office.15%29.aspx) SharePoint 2013 **completely** supports `IE9` browser.

The error *SP.Ribbon. is null or undefined* probably occurs since `SP.Ribbon.js` is not loaded when the specified code is executed.

Use [SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func, depScriptFileName) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411788%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to make sure that the user defined code is executed when the JavaScript library is loaded.

### Example

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    var InEditMode = SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.isInEditMode();
    if(!InEditMode){
       //...
    }
}, 'SP.Ribbon.js');
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me - I guess IE9 is just loading the scripts differently and it was pure luck it worked for the other browsers. Now works as expected - many thanks

Comment: Yep, it seems the IE9 rendering engine works differently in case of loading of scripts, Glad this helped you!